# Best APi solution for GoogleAnalytics

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am currently looking to integrate Google Analytics into Salesforce platform and understand the current limitations of this.

Is there a more powerful, recommendation(s) for an API integration?

Thank you very much in advance for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Does google analytics not provide all that's needed, maybe there is another thing within the google suite that they intend for people wanting to organize your info?

Yes, Salesforce can do all the API integration things. It can do them really well